# XSLT 3.0: Create element only if input element has data

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces, xslt-3.0

We are using `XSLT` internally to map a single input schema to a large number of distinct output schemas. Most of the servers using these schemas **return errors on empty elements**, so empty elements cannot appear in the output. In many cases, a piece of data in the input will simply map to a piece of data in the output, possibly with a minor transformation, e.g.:

```
<!-- Input -->
<ourns:DateCreated>2021-12-09</ourns:DateCreated>

<!-- Output -->
<otherns:CreatedDt>2021-12-09<otherns:CreatedDt>
```

The XSLT for this is straightforward, even with the "no empty elements" requirement:

```
<xsl:if test="ourns:DateCreated != ''">
  <otherns:CreatedDt>
    <xsl:value-of select="ourns:DateCreated/text()"/>
  </otherns:CreatedDt>
</xsl:if>
```

However, when you're mapping thousands of elements across hundreds of schemas, this business of wrapping everything in `<xsl:if/>` gets tiresome. You could add a function, say:

```
<xsl:function name="ourfn:createElementIfData">
  <xsl:param name="tag" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:if test="$data != ''">
    <xsl:element name="{$tag}"><xsl:value-of select="$data"/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
...
<xsl:sequence select="ourfn:createElementIfData('otherns:CreatedDt', ourns:DateCreated)"/>
```

But this function will only work if it lives in a stylesheet where both namespaces are declared. If you wanted to share it (as you probably would such a general-purpose function), you would end up needing to either

1. Declare every possible `otherns` in the shared stylesheet, or
2. Pass in the fully qualified namespace on every invocation,

both of which feel wrong.

This seems like such a common use case that I feel like there must be a simple way to do it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could define your basic rules like this:

```
<xsl:template match="ourns:DateCreated" 
              mode="copySimpleElement">
  <otherns:CreatedDt>{.}</otherns:CreatedDt>
</xsl:template>
```

and then override it for empty elements:

```
<xsl:template match="*[. = '']" 
              mode="copySimpleElement" 
              priority="20"/>
```

and then you just have to apply-templates to the relevant elements in the appropriate mode.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown any context but perhaps `<xsl:template match="ourns:*[not(has-children())]"/>` suffices to prevent any processing of the elements without content and adding `<xsl:template match="ourns:DateCreated[has-children()]" expand-text="yes"><otherns:CreatedDt>{.}</otherns:CreatedDt></xsl:template>` suffices to map the non-empty element to the wanted output element.

Of course `<xsl:template match="ourns:*[not(has-children())]"/>` could be set up as `<xsl:template match="*[not(has-children())]"/>`  if the rule can be applied to input elements from any namespace or can take a sequence of patterns with `<xsl:template match="ourns:*[not(has-children())] | ourns2:*[not(has-children())]"/>`.

All the above assumes you are processing those nodes through other templates e.g. the identity transformation `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`.

If you want to take the function approach I would check if you can pass in an `xs:QName`:

```
<xsl:function name="ourfn:createElementIfData">
  <xsl:param name="node-name" as="xs:QName"/>
  <xsl:param name="data" as="xs:string"/>
  <xsl:if test="$data != ''">
    <xsl:element name="{$node-name}" namespace="{namespace-uri-from-QName($node-name)}"><xsl:value-of select="$data"/></xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:function>
```

and use e.g. `<xsl:sequence select="ourfn:createElementIfData(QName('http://yourothernamespace/', 'otherns:CreatedDt'), ourns:DateCreated)"/>`.